# Python basics: argument input help needed, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, audio, spectrogram

I'm trying to test a Python script that hopefully produces an audio spectrogram from a wav file. I assume I need to input a path to a wav, but I am getting an error: IndexError: list index out of range when I tried it by entering it here:

```
sr,x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('mySoundFile.wav')
```

I also tried the path as an argument in the command line, but I am not getting it right. Any help?

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/chicago/2010-December/007314.html

```
"""
Compute and display a spectrogram.
Give WAV file as input
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile
import numpy as np
import sys

wavfile = sys.argv[1]

sr,x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('BeatBoy01.wav')

## Parameters: 10ms step, 30ms window
nstep = int(sr * 0.01)
nwin  = int(sr * 0.03)
nfft = nwin

window = np.hamming(nwin)

## will take windows x[n1:n2].  generate
## and loop over n2 such that all frames
## fit within the waveform
nn = range(nwin, len(x), nstep)

X = np.zeros( (len(nn), nfft/2) )

for i,n in enumerate(nn):
    xseg = x[n-nwin:n]
    z = np.fft.fft(window * xseg, nfft)
    X[i,:] = np.log(np.abs(z[:nfft/2]))

plt.imshow(X.T, interpolation='nearest',
    origin='lower',
    aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you didn't pass any arguments, this line `wavfile = sys.argv[1]` will raise `IndexError`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid may have it, but if not, can you post the full traceback from your `IndexError`? That will tell us precisely where the error is occurring.

Comment: Macintosh:Desktop wolf$ cd spectro/
Macintosh:spectro wolf$ ls
BeatBoy01.wav spectro1.py
Macintosh:spectro wolf$ python spectro1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spectro1.py", line 10, in <module>
    wavfile = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this try/except to get around the `IndexError`:

```
try:
   wavefile = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
   wavfile = 'BeatBoy01.wav'

sr,x = scipy.io.wavfile.read(wavfile)
```

This effectively sets the default file to `BeatBoy01.wav` if no argument is passed to the script.  Keep in mind that `BeatBoy01.wav` should be in the same directory from where the script is executed for this to work.

For easier argument parsing, have a look at the [`OptParse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) library.

Comment: The imported name is `scipy.io.wavefile` which doesn't conflict with the local name `wavefile`. Even if you were right, it would not raise an `IndexError`.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use "**wavfile**" as a variable, it is the name of the library.

Try this:

```
inputFile = sys.argv[1]

sr,x = scipy.io.wavfile.read(inputFile)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That can't be the issue. The `wavfile` module isn't located in the script's local namespace, but rather in the `scipy.io` package namespace. The local variable `wavfile` doesn't shadow it. It might have been an issue if the import statement was `from scipy.io import wavfile`, but that's not what's in the current code.

Comment: That is not the issue - but more importantly - even if it were, it would not raise `IndexError`.